# Python simple splitter

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to count until it finds an "@" sign and then counts how many letters it took to find so I can work with that
I tried this simple code but can't seem to find what issues it has
I am expecting
@
6
in this case but it gives no output at all

```
email = "email@gmail.com"
length = len(email)
count = 0
counter = email[count]
counter
for i in range(length):
    if counter == "@":
        print(counter)
        print(count)
        i  = 0
    else:
        count = count + 1
```

Comment: Please state how the output differs from what you expected/wanted.

Comment: I am expecting 
@
6
 in this case but it gives no output at all

Comment: Please add that to the question. You are getting no output because you never update the value of `counter`

Comment: shouldn't calling it using ```counter``` be enough?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want the string index where the @ is, why not use string.index()

```
>>> email = "email@gmail.com"
>>> email.index('@')
5
```

Comment: I guess this is intended as a programming exercise in writing an explicit loop, but you are of course absolutely correct.

Comment: I am not doing it for a project I am doing it just to make sure I am getting the hang of all what I have learned so far, but I will make sure I remember using that in the future

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the variable `counter` *inside* the loop. You also do not need the `count` variable, because you already have `i`, which is the iteration number (starting from 0).  Based on your description, you also need to break from the loop when you find an `@` sign, in case there is more than one (even though for an email address there should not be).

So you can do:

```
email = "email@gmail.com"
length = len(email)
for i in range(length):
    counter = email[i]
    if counter == "@":
        print(counter)
        print(i+1)
        break
```

You can also simplify the code by using the `enumerate` function to give you `i` and `counter` at the same time as you iterate over the email:

```
email = "email@gmail.com"
for i, counter in enumerate(email):
    if counter == "@":
        print(counter)
        print(i+1)
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you aren't setting the value of counter inside the loop, it gets set to the first value and then never set again. You also need to set counter to email[i], since i is your variable that increments.

The following code works:

```
email = "email@gmail.com"
length = len(email)
count = 0
for i in range(length):
    counter = email[i] # This is the line I changed!
    if counter == "@":
        print(counter)
        print(count)
        i  = 0
    else:
        count = count + 1
```

Keep in mind that since indexes start at 0, you get an output of "@ 5".